# Get all members from country depending on multiple tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 4 tables, filled with some example data

**user table**

```
id | name  | idAddress | 
------------------------
1  | Bernd | 1         | 
2  | Max   | 2         |
3  | Tom   | 3         |
4  | Bob   | 4         |
5  | Alice | 5         |
```

**address**

```
id | country |  zip  |
----------------------
1  | DE      | 39213 |
2  | CH      | 13847 |
3  | NL      | 38472 |
4  | DE      | 94872 |
5  | MT      | 54682 |
6  | US      |  4682 |
7  | DE      | 45853 |
8  | NA      | 12144 |
```

**orga2Address**

```
idOrga   | idAddress |
------------------
1        | 6         | 
1        | 7         |
2        | 7         |
2        | 8         |
```

**orga2User**

```
idUser | idOrga |
-----------------
1      | 1      | 
1      | 2      |
2      | 1      |
3      | 2      |
4      | 2      |
```

I want to select all user names that have address in 'DE' in the **user table** or that are in an orga which has an address in 'DE' in **orga2Address**.

I was able to get the result with the UNION command like this (see this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72e4f7/1)):

```
SELECT `name`, `country` FROM (SELECT `user`.`name`, `address`.`country` from `user` 
INNER JOIN `address` ON `user`.`idAddress` = `address`.`id`
UNION
SELECT  `user`.`name` from `user` 
INNER JOIN `orga2User` `o2U` ON `o2U`.`idUser` = `user`.`id`
INNER JOIN `orga2Address` `o2A` ON `o2A`.`idOrga` = `o2U`.`idOrga` 
INNER JOIN `address` `a` ON `a`.`id` = `o2A`.`idAddress`) as `U` WHERE `U`.`country`="DE";
```

**The result**

```
name   |
--------
Bernd  |
Max    |
Tom    |
Bob    |
```

Is there a quicker and better way to get the wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more compact formulation ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72e4f7/11)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.name, address.country
    FROM orga2Address
        INNER JOIN orga2User
            ON orga2User.idOrga = orga2Address.idOrga
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN user
            ON user.id = orga2User.idUser
        INNER JOIN address
            ON address.id IN (user.idAddress, orga2Address.idAddress)
    WHERE address.country = 'DE';
```

The trick is, instead of `UNION`, perform a `JOIN` with more than one join path.  (We unfortunately need to use `DISTINCT`, but that is no worse than your `UNION`, which also de-duplicates results.)

In addition, I suggest:

- formatting your code with better indentation.  In this example, the `SELECT` statement has a `FROM` clause and a `WHERE` clause.  The `FROM` clause has multiple `JOIN`s, each of which has an `ON` clause.
- using single quotes for string literals like `'DE'`, which is standard ANSI SQL.  [Using double quotes for strings is a MySQLism](//stackoverflow.com/a/1992392/1157100), and it fails if [`SQL_MODE = 'ANSI_QUOTES'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) is in force.
- avoid overdoing the `` `quotes` ``.  If you didn't need them in your `CREATE TABLE` statements, you don't need them in your query either.

Comment: Thank you. Is your compact formulation also quicker, or just more readable? Would it improve the SQL if one would remove the WHERE clause and change `ON address.id IN` to `ON address.id AND address.country = 'DE' IN`  ?

Comment: Definitely don't absorb the `WHERE` clause into the join condition — it's less readable. (With `OUTER JOIN`s, the meaning would also change when you do that.)

Comment: Is it quicker? Probably not, and in fact could be slower if MySQL doesn't know how to handle such join conditions efficiently. Time it both ways yourself to see if it makes a difference for your data set.